# AB testing in Test and Target

Tags: ab-testing, test-and-target

Using Adobe Test and Target, I know I can setup mboxes and push various pieces of content into them for testing purposes.  But how do I test two seperate versions of a homepage against one another?  Is this something that can be test in test and target?

Do I just make one big mbox that holds the whole homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an mBox that 'redirects' to the versions of your homepage.   You can do this by setting up separate experiences, and splitting your campaign based on a traffic split, or via some other metric.

For example, you can simply have one mbox that has two offers pointed to it.   The first "offer" could simply do a default content - which would be your control.

The second "offer/experience" could simply be a java-script redirect to your alternative homepage.

You can then add multiple experiences/offers all posted to the same box that do similar tings to have a ABCD type of test.

I would avoid putting too much code in an mbox, as its loaded dynamically and can have performance impacts.   I think a simple redirect to a static HTML page is a better way to go.